# Set Windows Application to use a proxy server

Tags: windows, proxy

I downloaded a windows app that is connecting to the Internet to get data from the external source. My network uses proxy server that requires authentication so whenever that app is trying to get online, it returns a 407 error.

I tried to use `netsh` to import IE proxy settings for `winhttp`, but it doesn't seem to help.

Is there any way I can set up this specific app or set universal proxy settings for all Windows apps?

Comment: superuser.com might get you better luck

Comment: superuser.com and check Control Panel, Internet Options, Connections